# Alternative term/phrase to 'Rule of thumb'?

Tags: phrases, expressions, meaning-in-context

I like using the term 'rule of thumb'.
e.g., *"As a **rule of thumb** it takes 10,000 hrs of practice to master a skill"*

However it has come to my attention that it it *may* have a [less than favorable origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_thumb#Folk_etymology)

Therefore I would like to use a different phrase to indicate the same thing.

**So what would be an an alternative term/phrase to 'Rule of thumb'?**

Comment: Etymology does not equal current "connotation." Many, perhaps most, native speakers use the phrase being happily ignorant of and not curious about the etymology.

Comment: @DarcyThomas: Did you read to the end of your link? Or even read the title of the section? "Folk etymology" is not actual etymology, and the theory (as far as my reading of that article) has been debunked.

Comment: @AndyT The funny thing about words is that they mean what people think they mean. (Yes I know that sounds like a tautology, but it's not) Sure you and I know the actual root meaning of the term. However many people have been told and understand a different origin. The meaning of words changes over time. e.g., [geek](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/geek )The point of writing or speaking is to communicate. If I am using a term which causes my audience to slip gears, then I am not doing the best I can to communicate with them. Ergo the reason I asked this question.

Answer (score 3):

You can omit the reference to the thumb and simply shorten it to

> As a rule it takes 10,000 hours of practice to master a skill.

It isn't really a *rule*, but an idiom as given in [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/as_a_rule)

> **as a rule**
>   PHRASE
>
> Usually, but not always.

Comment: Lexico also provides a [list of synonyms to "as a rule"](https://www.lexico.com/en/synonym/as_a_rule). I imagine that depending on the context some of them could also be used.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is possibly too short and simple to be an ‘answer’ at all.  A rule of thumb is nothing more than a *rough guide*.

There are well known ‘rules of thumb.  In addition to the measurement of portions of rice, are many other forms of approximation:  converting between various measures, including between imperial and metric, or celsius and fahrenheit.  These can be called *rough guides*.

There are, indeed ‘general rules’, already mentioned, but these are rather different.  Those are generalisations about things that are often or usually but not always true.  This distinction is is a useful one, worth retaining.

Answer (score 2):

> Rule of Thumb:
>
> A practical and approximate way of doing or measuring something:
>
> *A good rule of thumb is that a portion of rice is two handfuls.*

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rule-of-thumb)

I would suggest using the word '**approximation**', instead.

"A good approximation is that a portion of rice is two handfuls."

> Approximation:
>
> a guess of a number that is not exact but that is close:

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/approximation)

The original saying was exactly that, an *approximation* of the diameter.

Comment: One may as well simplify it: *A portion of rice is roughly two handfuls.*